Premium P3V3 App Service Plan - rules based resource allocation does not go more than 10 instances
In our Azure account we have purchased a Premium P3V3 App Service Plan. We use rules based resource allocation generally using the time scheduling tools to handle scaling up and down as needed. We have noticed that the maximum number of instances that we ought to be able to scale to is 30, but we are not able to set the scale instances to any number more than 10. Why is this? Is this a bug or is there some action we need to take?

Check if below solution helps to resolve the issue.


We have noticed that the maximum number of instances that we ought to be able to scale to is 30, but we are not able to set the scale instances to any number more than 10.

This could happen if the region you have created the App Service Plan does not have enough instances available to satisfy the request as mentioned in MS Q&A.
It happens if the region has a high number of new web apps already being created which leads to the difficulties in keeping up with demand.
To resolve this:

create a new App Service Plan in a different region.
Perform scale-out operation using Automatic Scaling method to scale the instances more than 10.
Switch to Rule-Based method and perform the scale-out again.

Initially, I was unable to scale out the instances more than 10 and got the below error.

Then tried to Scale-out using Automatic Scale-out method after some time and I was able to increase the instance count up to 30.

After this, I have switched to Rule-based method and able to scale-out more than 10 instances.

Created an App Service Plan(P3V3) in East US region.

Able to scale out the instances up to 30 using Rule-Based method.

Make sure the Automatic scaling is not enabled.



Updated Current instance after scale-out operation:



